# Verification emails not working since migrating my Parse app's MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, email, parse-platform, passwords, reset

I've completed step 1 of my Parse migration by moving to my own MongoDB server. Everything is working fine except emails sent by Parse.com. Again, I've only migrated the DB so the cloud code (and Parse REST API) are still being hosted by Parse.com.

Clicking on any email verification or password reset email link ends with the "Invalid Link" error page. I've confirmed the token and username in the emails are correct.

My only thought is the Parse.com hosted email verification handler is not able to communicate with the external MongoDB server I migrated to (but the the Parse.com REST API is working fine so that doesn't make sense).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue.

Comment: Same, any solutions? We've migrated to mLabs and email verification links are now failing.

Comment: Same issue for us too. This issue was reported to Facebook Parse team on Feb 18th. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/236366263364291/

Answer (score 0):

sorry to inform you that the only option for us was to transfer the parse server code in github to our on server in Heroku..

I don't think this problem is going to be solved in parse.com...
but the guys on the parse server on github are doing magic! 
And aomost completely transferred the entire parse.com server and it's full functionality into the github source code..it was not simple to transfer ourselves to a combination of mLab, parse-server open source, Heroku and oneSignal, but now, after many changes and fixes were made to the source code it workes like a charm :) kudos to the guys at parse server in github for their magnificent work!!!

Anyway, if any of you have questions regarding the transfer to use the combination mentioned above, you are welcome to make this post into a Q&A for transferring parse.com into your own server...
(As long as the admins will let us do this)